# How does the elastic search calculate the current date when using the 'now' keyword?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example consider the following elastic query:

```
GET /my_docs/_search
{ 
     "query": {  

                 "range": {  
                    "doc_creation_date": {  
                      "gte": "2007-07-18T10:15:13"  
                      "lt": "now"
                    }
                 }
     }
}
```

So my question is:
when elastic search replaces the word 'now' in the above query - with an actual date - does it just use the date of the server its currently running on or 
what other option is going on there?

The reason i am asking this is because i live in a place where the timezone changes depending on the time of the year. So between around March - October, we are at utc

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`now` is resolved to the Unix timestamp of the server in milliseconds.

The Unix timestamp is an epoch date defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970 [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time]

This means that all queries will be run against the UTC time zone unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is what i thought, but wanted to be sure.